# Collision script on an object to be collided with from the player for pickup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to write a script that allows the player to walk into a pack of ammo (or health) and gain something from doing so. I'm struggling with the actual collision part of this as no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to work. I currently have this script on my ammo pack object.

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Collided");
    }
}
```

My ammo pack object has a collider on it (currently capsule, will be box for final product) that has "Is Trigger" enabled.
My player has a capsule collider also (non-trigger) and a rigidbody with gravity enabled and everything else default. It is also tagged as "Player". When my player walks into the ammo pack, there is no message printed.

I've tried several solutions that involve changing triggers on colliders and rigidbody kinematic settings but none of them seem to work. I'm using Unity 5 and so I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are they both using the same Collider? Collider is for 3D and Collider2D is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will never get called because your capitalisation is wrong. Capitalise the first letter of the function name.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
```

Instead of:

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider c)
```

Note: Always use `CompareTag()` instead of `==` to compare strings. Both work but CompareTag is GC friendly.

Comment: Funny eh, I syntax colouring is pointing at the right answer.

Comment: I cannot believe I was that stupid. In MonoDevelop, the function name isn't coloured (even if it is right). I'm just too used to the lowercase starter letter for some things. Thank you for the help!
EDIT: GC friendly?

Comment: It will reduce the need for garbage collection. This is a documented issue.